# Strange behaviour with pstricks/TikZ/center

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, auto-pst-pdf

I'm working on a long document (written by someone else). The author has used a lot of pstricks pictures, and I'd like to compile the document using pdflatex (without doing the detour over dvi). The documentclass depends on TikZ, and I've noticed the following very strange behaviour.

Compliling

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Works if we don't load tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}

\begin{document}

% Works if we load tikz, but don't use center
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture*}(-3.24,-1.49)(10.23,5.7)
\psline(-1,0)(6,0)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

the auto-pst-pdf phase crashes with a Ghostscript error:

```
"-------------------------------------------------"
"auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation"
"-------------------------------------------------"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded format=latex)
entering extended mode
Error: /typecheck in --div--
Operand stack:
   1   0   0.0   TeXcolorgray   65781.8
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1932   1   3   %oparray_pop   1931   1   3   %oparray_pop   1915   1   3   %oparray_pop   1803   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   5   --nostringval--   %repeat_continue   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1180/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:118/200(L)--   --dict:173/300(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 91942
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.

!!! Warning: Empty Bounding Box is returned by Ghostscript!
!!!   Page 1: 0 0 0 0
!!! Either there is a problem with the page or with Ghostscript.
!!! Recovery is tried by embedding the page in its original size.

==> 1 page written on `basic-pics.pdf'.
"-------------------------------------------------"
"auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation"
"-------------------------------------------------"
```

---

If I don't load TikZ, everything works ok. Weirdly, if I remove the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`, everthing works ok too.

This is running TexLive14 on a Windows machine, but the same thing happens on a recent version of MacTex on a Mac machine.

In the end, the `center` environment won't be there, and the problem will go away by itself. Nevertheless, I'd be interested in a fix or at least any ideas where to dig for the problem. I haven't used pstricks and auto-pst-pdf much myself.

---

**Update** Apparantly, `center` wasn't the full story. I redefined the `center`-environment into a dummy do-nothing, and all seemed (sort-of) well until I compiled the full document with the real documentclass. The documentclass builds on memoir, using the `showtrims` option. Without showtrims, everything is ok, but with it I get the same errors as above.

Is there a way to configure auto-pst-pdf to use a different document class for its temporary creation of figures?

Comment: No errors running `pdflatex` here using TeXlive 2014 on Linux. But the PDF output has 2 blank pages. Normal with `latex` and the DVI ouput has one single page with the horizontal line.

Comment: @Sigur Look at the log file. The error is on GS level.

Comment: @percusse, yes. You're right. The `log` file shows: *!!! Warning: Empty Bounding Box is returned by Ghostscript!
!!!   Page 1: 0 0 0 0
!!! Either there is a problem with the page or with Ghostscript.
!!! Recovery is tried by embedding the page in its original size.*

Comment: If you compile with `xelatex` (removing the `[pdf]` option), there is no problem.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, but that causes other problems (letterspacing small caps doesn't work with xelatex at least not with microtype, textls). Also compiling this document with xelatex is **extremely** slow.

Comment: If I were you, I would put each diagram (either coded in PSTricks or TikZ or others) in a separate compilable input file (usually we use `standalone` document class), compile it with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` (for PSTricks and TikZ) or `pdflatex` (for TikZ) to obtain a PDF version for each diagram. Then you can import all the diagrams (in PDF) from within your main input file and compile the main input file with `pdflatex`. With this approach, you can get many advantages: 1. you can use `microtype`, 2. your input files are easy to maintain, 3. you can reduce the compilation time, 4. etc.

Comment: @InPSTrickswetrust Yes, the thought did occur to me. A downside is that the original author will have to work further with the document, and he's not very tech-savvy. That solution might be too complicated for him. (Also, there are hundreds of figures and I'd rather not spend the time stripping the figures out of the tex-files, even if that step can be somewhat automated.)

Comment: Avoid the `minimal` class.

Comment: @egreg I don't really use the minimal class, but I thought it was still the recommended one for MWE:s

Comment: @mrf See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided

Comment: @mrf: XeLaTeX is very slow in general for the first compilation, much less slow for subsequent compilations. As for letterspacing, `fontspec` can use  directly the `LetterSpace=…` font feature of Opentype fonts.

Answer (score 4):

It works for me if I add `\leavevmode` before `\begin{pspicture*}`.

I guess this has to do with the changes TikZ makes to some of the innards of LaTeX, but going through the details could be very challenging.

Since adding `\leavevmode` shouldn't be a concern, because direct inclusion in the vertical list is something that should be avoided in LaTeX anyway, you can add

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{pspicture*}{\leavevmode\pspicture*}
\makeatother
```

to your document preamble.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the `center` problem, but alas not the `showtrims` one. I posted my alternative workaround which seems to take care of both issues.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I found a workable "solution". Patching the documentclass with

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,fleqn,showtrims]{memoir}
\else
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,fleqn]{memoir}
\fi
```

and a similar guard where TikZ is loaded

```
\ifpdf
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\fi
```

sorts everything out. The actual guarding is done via an option for the documentclass, so that TikZ still loads normally regardless of whether we're compiling to pdf or not when the workaround is not needed.